# Baking from script on Blender 4.0

Tags: python, scripting, particles, physics, baking

This is the code required to bake a particle system on Blender 3.6:

```
import bpy

# Get scene
scene_name = 'Scene'
scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(scene_name)
if scene is None:
    print(f"No se encontró la escena {scene_name}")
    exit()

# Get particle system
ps_name = "Boid"
degp = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
ps_object = bpy.data.objects[ps_name]
particle_system = ps_object.evaluated_get(degp).particle_systems[0]

# Free bake
override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': ps_object, 'point_cache': particle_system.point_cache}
bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)

# Bake
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
print("Baked!")
```

In Blender 4.0, this script throws the following error:

```
ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported
```

According to [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ptcache.html), `bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake()` does not support any parameters. However if this function is called without parameters it throws the following error as it is expecting context to be provided:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.ptcache.bake.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

How to bake physics and particle systems from script in Blender 4.0?